# Chrome extension alternatives to local storage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, storage

I'm looking for a storage mechanism which will persist across websites. I've got primitive data types numbers / strings which I need to store. localStorage doesn't work for me because it falls under the same origin policy. I need my data to be the same across all websites but much be tab specific and accessed via contentscripts.

Could someone suggest a suitable mechanism for achieveing this?

**EDIT:**
I'm currently implementing the first answers code and not having much look. I've got the following...

background.html

note: tabStorage is a class variable in this function

```
    function store(){
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.req == "save") {
        tabStorage[sender.tab.id] = request.data;
       }

    if(request.req == "load") {
        sendResponse(tabStorage[sender.tab.id]);
    }
    });
}
```

contentscript.js

response is returning `undefined`

```
 chrome.extension.sendRequest({req: "load"}, function(response) {
            console.log("getting stak");
            console.log(response.data);
 });
```

what am I doing wrong? the code is accessing both load and save so I know it's getting there and back but undefined is returning. why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use extension's own localStorage which you access from a background page. If you need this information in a content script, you need to send a request to a background page using [messaging](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html), read it there, and send a result back to a content script in a response.

**UPDATE**
If you don't need the storage to keep values between browser restarts then you don't need the localStorage. Just store everything in a background page and identify tabs by their ids. Background page will keep the values as long as the browser is opened. For example:

**content script:**

```
//save
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "save", data: {param1: "value1", param2: "value2"});
...
//load
chrome.extension.sendRequest({cmd: "load"}, function(response) {
    console.log("tab data:", response)
});
```

**background page:**

```
var tabStorage = [];
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.cmd == "save") {
        tabStorage[sender.tab.id] = request.data;
    }

    if(request.cmd == "load") {
        sendResponse(tabStorage[sender.tab.id]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Background page wont allow me to keep things on a per tab basis tho, right? I want different values for different tabs.

Comment: @Skizit what do you mean by tab - domain or actual tab?

Comment: I mean actual tab like the tabs within the browser. I want each tab to have it's own storage.

Comment: @Skizit Do you want this storage to be cleaned after browser restart?

Comment: If you want localStorage to be unique for each tab, you can store it normally within the content script. By accessing the localStorage in the content script, it will be just for that webpage.

Comment: Yes, but thats the thing... I don't want it to be just for that webpage. I want storage which is unique to each tab but is also the same across all websites within that tab.

Comment: @Skizit So is it ok if the storage will be cleared after each browser restart? If not then how are you going to identify tabs between browser restarts?

Comment: @Skizit First, don't put request listener inside `store()` function, it should be at the top level. Second, when data is loaded you should use `response`, not `response.data`.